# Where to declare ConfigurationManger inside aclass library?

Tags: c#, winforms, class-library, configurationmanager

I am developing a Windows form application with C# language in vs2017. I have a local SQL database that I access a lot from different winform.
I wanted to create a static class library that contains static methods to read or add data to my database just to make my program neat and easy to read.

Usually, I was declaring my `ConfigurationManger` in winform with `initializeComponent()`, but inside my class library I am getting an error if
 I declare it inside my class, I can declare it only inside my method, but that means I have to declare it inside all my methods which is not the right way to do I think.

So, I am asking what is the best way to do it?

This is my declaration:

```
connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GTC_Frater_Razes.Properties.Settings.db_alarmeConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

which provides the following error message

> "ConfigurationManger.ConnectionStrings does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Declare it inside a constructor of your ViewSet?

Comment: One good practice is to have App.config file for this kind of applications.

Comment: @Amit, i have App.config, how can i use it in this case?

Comment: @lawir if you show us your declaration of `ConfigurationManager` and how you use it for database connection, it will be easy for us to provide you work around for that

Comment: @MohibWasay, i don't know what do you mean by ViewSet, could you be more specific please?

Comment: "i am getting an error if i declare it inside my class," - errors contain useful information. Even if you don't understand what the error is saying, **sharing** the error with us with be a good start.

Comment: @Amit, i just edited my post if you want to check it out .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you're right i'm sorry, my error says that "ConfigurationManger.ConnectionStrings does not exist in the current context" . i assumed it is not a very useful information because i'm doing it completly wrong and that's why i didn't share the error.

Comment: @lawir , I have given an answer, try this approach. and let us know if it works for you or you still have some problem.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming in your class library you have class, `DataProvider`

```
public class DataProvider
{
    private static string m_connectionString;

    public static void SetConnectionString()
    {
        //Or you can use your conventional way to get connection string, but as you can see this call will be one time only, It will help you.
        m_connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connString"]; 
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataFromDataBase(string query)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(m_connectionString))
        {
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
             MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             da.Fill(tbl);
        }
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

that static method of DataProvider `SetConnectionString()` should be called in early part of software run time, ideadly at startup.
and Static method `GetDataFromDataBase()` will accept a query and return data table with data of database.

Thus (in general winform case), your static class `Program` in `Program.cs` file will be look like,

```
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            DataProvider.SetConnectionString();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
```

In your App.config you should have a tags

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connString" value="server=<serverIP>;user id=<user>;database=<databaseName>;pooling=true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't have that tags, i have the connection string i shared before . is that different ?

Comment: No, at the end, it must a string. they both would be the same. benefit of have it in .config file is that it will provide you flexibility to change it. as it will be in external and you will not need to build your app again and again to change it.

Comment: Okay, and when should i call the "SetConnectionString()" method ? each time before call a "SetData" or "GetData" ?

Comment: @lawir no.. it is the benefit of having such architecture, SetConnectionString() method should be called only once when you start the software. afterwards just GetData()/SetData()

Comment: sorry i was busy. not yet, i don't know what to put instead of ""connString" in your case, because i don't have the appSettings tags in my app.config .

Comment: and when you say at the start of the software, could be more specific? im using a winform application

Comment: @lawir you can always add <appSettings> tag inside of <configuration> tag in your app.config. and by mean of software start (in winform) you can call it in program.cs file (thus it will be called even before main form appear) I have updated my answer accordingly.